# Understanding JAX argnums parameter in its gradient function

Tags: python, automatic-differentiation, jax

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of `argnums` in JAX's gradient function.
Suppose I have the following function:

```
def make_mse(x, t):  
  def mse(w,b): 
    return np.sum(jnp.power(x.dot(w) + b - t, 2))/2
  return mse
```

And I'm taking the gradient in the following way:

```
w_gradient, b_gradient = grad(make_mse(train_data, y), (0,1))(w,b)
```

`argnums= (0,1)` in this case, but what does it mean? With respect to which variables the gradient is calculated? What will be the difference if I will use `argnums=0` instead?
Also, can I use the same function to get the Hessian matrix?

I looked at [JAX help](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax.html#jax.jacfwd) section about it, but couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you pass multiple argnums to grad, the result is a function that returns a tuple of gradients, equivalent to if you had computed each separately:

```python
def f(x, y):
  return x ** 2 + x * y + y ** 2

df_dxy = grad(f, argnums=(0, 1))
df_dx = grad(f, argnums=0)
df_dy = grad(f, argnums=1)

x = 3.0
y = 4.25
assert df_dxy(x, y) == (df_dx(x, y), df_dy(x, y))
```

If you want to compute a mixed second derivatives, you can do this by repeatedly applying the gradient:

```python
d2f_dxdy = grad(grad(f, argnums=0), argnums=1)
assert d2f_dxdy(x, y) == 1
```